# Some of my model doesnt render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am sure this is just something stupid. The main model doesn't render, just the eyes and the beard for some reason!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here : http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: none of that worked. Is still just rendering the beard. where do I put my blend file up?

Comment: See the link already mentioned by @lemon

Comment: whoops! thatnkyou. will upload

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2700" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2700/)

Comment: It is due to the particles system : go to the particles panel, then "render" then check "emitter". This is a way to choose if the emitter of the particles is displayed or not

Comment: you are a diamond. cheers dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at your blend and it is because when you added the beard (Particle system) you told blender to hide the model.

Just check this box.

[image]